# Get data from pouchdb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I have successfully put the information into PouchDB, but how can I retrieve the data and show in HTML using AngularJS?

```
var db = new PouchDB('infoDB');

function getData(){
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    var row = data[0].Row;
    var info = [];

    db.destroy().then(function () {
        return new PouchDB('infoDB');
    }).then(function(db){
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            var info = {
                _id: row[i].id,
                name: row[i].name, 
                email: row[i].email,
                age: row[i].age
            }
            db.put(info).then(function(result){
                console.log("Everything is ok!");
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log('Oh No!');
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    });
});
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

look for fetching documents from your pouchdb database.

on their website they briefly explain:
https://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document

to fetch a specific document, look into the find plugin:
https://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/
it's easy to use and also works with Couch 2.0.

I'm not able to help you with angular i'm afraid.